# Script that runs fine on PowerShell returns error using System.Management.Automation.PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a C# program that uses PowerShell to renew certificates by LetsEncrypt, but I can't get passed the first line.

My code:

```cs
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    ps.AddScript("Import-Module ACMESharp");
    ps.Invoke();

    output = ps.HadErrors
        ? ps.Streams.Error.ToString()
        : ps.Streams.Information.ToString();
    return !ps.HadErrors;
}
```

The result is that I'm getting an error:

> The specified module 'ACMESharp' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

but when I run the same command in PowerShell, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your codes fails when running it without Administrator privileges and works when running it as Admin.

Set your C# app to run with Admin privileges:

1. If you are running in Visual Studio and debugging only, run the Visual Studio as "`Administrator`".
2. If you are planing to deploy the application, your need add this to your [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)).

   ```
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
   ```

**Edit:**

Another reason for `Import-Module` to fail is that specified module `ACMESharp` does not exist in the `PSModulePath` variable. In this case, there is no way for `PowerShell` to find the module to import.

You could explicitly add another path by appending the path to the existing PSModulePath list of paths.

```
var extraModulesPath = "somepath";
var state = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
using (var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(state))
{
    rs.Open();
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.Runspace = rs;
        var psModulePath = rs.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("env:PSModulePath");
        rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("env:PSModulePath", $"{psModulePath};{extraModulesPath}");

        ps.AddScript("Import-Module('ACMESharp')");
        ps.Invoke();

        var output = ps.HadErrors
            ? ps.Streams.Error.ToString()
            : ps.Streams.Information.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply - but I'm getting the exact same result.

Comment: What is your PS version? Run $PSVersionTable.PSVersion to get it.

Comment: Importing a module never requires administrative privileges, so I suggest removing the first part of the answer. Appending to `$env:PSModulePath` sounds like the right approach, though it's easier to include that in the code passed to `.AddScript()`. Please avoid pseudo method syntax such as `Import-Module('ACMESharp')`. @EylM: Interactively, after successfully importing the module, run `(Get-Module ACMESharp).Path` to determine the module's directory. Consider installing it in a directory that is present in `$env:PSModulePath` _by default_.

Comment: Sorry, meant to address you, @user884248, in my previous comment.