# System.Management.Automation.Powershell enable-psremoting is missing pwrshplugin.dll

Tags: c#, powershell

The following piece of code is from a project of mine that is doing something with PSRemoting. I encountered an issue as the following piece of code

```cs
ps.AddScript("enable-psremoting -force -skipnetworkprofilecheck");
await ps.InvokeAsync();
```

will cause the following error to happen

```
System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: 'The running command stopped 
because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 
'C:\Users\pa3ck\Desktop\MP\RemotePowerShell\RemotePowershell\bin\Debug\net6.0-
windows\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\pwrshplugin.dll' because it does not exist.'
```

I assume I'm missing some NuGet package, but I have no clue which at this point

I have the following NuGet packages installed and active in the project:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK (7.2.7)
- Microsoft.WSMan.Management (7.2.7)
- Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime (7.2.7)
- System.Management.Automation (7.2.7)

Comment: Do a search on your machine for file pwrshplugin.dll.  Does it exist?  Check your powershell paths from cmd.exe >Set.  The path is PSModulePath.  The cmdlet must be on the path.  Either add the in the error message or move cmdlet int an existing powershell path.  Are you pa3ck?  If not only the admin or the user has access to the folder.  It looks like the cmdlet was not installed in a folder that everybody has access.  Move the cmdlet to a folder on everybody's path.

Comment: @jdweng yes that's my user account and the app was running in admin, due to other commands ran needing admin. Additionally, the app does not use the system installed powershell, but its own installation that was installed as part of the NuGet packages.

Comment: If you are running as Admin what is your PSModulePath?  The cmdlet is not being found on the path.  When you installed the cmdlet is got put on a different path.  Simply move the cmdlet to a folder on a better path.  You can either add the nuget path to the PSModulePath or move the cmdlet to an existing path.

Comment: @jdweng keep in mind we are not talking about windows powershell here, we are talking about `System.Management.Automation.Powershell` inside a C# application which is located together with the app itself. The command runs just fine in windows powershell

Comment: Now that I think about it, it might actually be better to just run that one command in a separate process, to ensure that it does everything as it should. As running it in a separate process would cause it to run in windows powershell

Comment: The app could be changing the PSModulePath.  Powershell check first for cmdlet in the active folder and then goes down the path in order until the cmdlet is found.  Remote PowerShell is running it own version of a cmdlet that is causing issues.  Found similar issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645236/script-that-runs-fine-on-powershell-returns-error-using-system-management-automa

Comment: @jdweng the app is not having trouble importing a module, the app is missing a dll which i assume is part of a NuGet Package that i am probably missing

Comment: The dll is part of the cmdlet.  The path contains "RemotePowerShell\RemotePowershell\bin" which is where the cmdlet is located.  The rest of the path is a subfolder.  If the cmdlet was located correctly I do not think you would have the error.

Comment: @jdweng oh those names might be a bit misleading. RemotePowerShell is the name of the solution and project. The path you just provided is the apps compiled output folder

Comment: Are you creating a custom cmdlet?  ps.AddScript("enable-psremoting -force -skipnetworkprofilecheck");  You are adding a new cmdlet enable-psremoting but not putting it on the PSModulePath.  Isn't that the real problem?

Comment: Powershell will look for a cmdlet in the current work directory and if it does not find the cmdlet than search the PSModulePath.  Look at existing folders under PSModulePath.  See if you project is organized like the standard cmdlets.  If not, modify you project so the missing dll is under the working folder or modify the PSModulePath so it finds you powershell module.

Comment: @jdweng that is quite literally how you run PowerShell commands inside c# the `ps` variable is an instance of PowerShell. This is c# not PowerShell. The method adds whatever is in the string into PowerShell, and once the invoke method is called all the PowerShell code there (In this case this 1 command) is run.